# Is it possible to initiate object as variable in liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm fairly new in Liquid environment and wonder if you could possibly initiate object variable in Liquid file as similar as JS?

```js
let person = [{
    'name' : 'John Doe',
    'age' : '20'
}];
```

I'm aware that liquid is using {% assign %} so is it any working ways of doing

```
{% assign person = [{
    'name' : 'John Doe',
    'age' : '20'
}]; %}
```

This is directly initialise it without pull any data from the metafields.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

You might use sompething like that:

```
{%- capture person -%}
name : John Doe , age : 20
{%- endcapture -%}
{% assign person = person | split:',' %}
```

Person is now an array.

```
{{ person.first }}
```

or

```
{{ person[0] }}
```

will output: `name : John Doe`.

Then, to go further:

```
{% assign person_name = person.first | split:':' %}
```

So

```
{{ person_name.last }}
```

or

```
{{ person_name[1] }}
```

will output: `John Doe`.

etc.

Comment: fantastic response, i'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create a new custom object in Shopify unless you have saved the object data in a metafield that you have defined and created in the Shopify editor.

The following is a way you can create and assign the object as a string and later on, use javascript to create a javascript object from the string.

```js
{% assign person = "[{'name' : 'John Doe','age' : '20'}]" %}

<script>
 var person = {{person}};
 //typeof(person) is object
</script>
```

Comment: Ahhh. I'll just wandering if it possible.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using liquidjs in a non-shopify environment, one solution I came across is using a custom Filter:

*idk if you can declare custom Filters in shopify*

write your object inside a capture block

```
{% capture table_data_json %}
  [
  {"key": "Marke", "value": "Audi"},
  {"key": "Größe", "value": "12m"}
  ]
{% endcapture %}
```

then register a new Filter which can create a JS Object from JSON

```
let engine = new Liquid({
  root: "...",
  extname: ".liquid", 
  layouts: ...,
  globals: ...,
});

// register new Filter
engine.registerFilter("jsonToObject", (json) => JSON.parse(json));
```

now you can use your new Filter to work with the returned Object

```
{% capture table_data_json %}
  [
  {"key": "Marke", "value": "Audi"},
  {"key": "Größe", "value": "12m"}
  ]
{% endcapture %}

{% assign table_object = table_data_json | jsonToObject %}

{% for table_data in table_object %}
  {{ table_data.key }} : {{ table_data.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to get a capture (string) into a JS-parsable state.

```json
  {%- capture ecommerce_item -%}
{
  "currency": "{{ currency.name }}",
  "value": "{{ product.price }}",
  "items": [ {
    "item_id": "SKU_{{ product.variants[0].sku }}",
    "item_name": "{{ product.variants[0].title }}",
    "item_list_id": "list_name_example",
    "item_list_name": "List name example",
    "item_brand": "{{ product.vendor }}",
    "currency": "{{ currency.name }}",
    "location_id": "abc123def456",
    "quantity": 1,
    "index": 0,
    "affiliation": "{{ shop.name }}",
    {%- for collection in product.collections -%}
    "item_category{% if forloop.first != true %}{{ forloop.index }}{% endif %}": "{{ collection.handle }}",
    {%- endfor -%}
    "price": "{{ product.price }}"
  } ]
}
  {%- endcapture %}
```

Later, you can render it in your HTML. Example:

```html
<div id="example" data-ecommerce='{{- ecommerce_item | strip_newlines | strip_html | json -}}'>
```

It then can be fetched in JS:

```js
JSON.parse( document.getElementById( 'example' ).dataset.ecommerce );
```

Note that the HTML itself in the page source will be converted, so you will find `&quote` tags. They do *not* prevent you from parsing it and using it in as JavaScript object.

*I understand that this does not fully answer the question, but as it's related, I am leaving it here for later readers.*